# Simplifying with Assumptions without giving trivial assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, inequalities

Given a long list of independent rational expressions, I need to decide in a reliable but quick way whether or not it is possible for each to be purely negative.

Consider the following rational expression:

```
expr = ((-1)^(1/3)*(x^2 - y))/x^2
```

Then I would like something like:

```
Assuming[(# ∈ Reals)& /@ Variables[expr]   (* {x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals} *)
 , Simplify[expr ∈ Reals && expr < 0]]
```

to return `False` since `expr` can't be real and negative.  But it doesn't work.  I have to explicitly tell it that no combination of variables can be zero:

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals, y ≠ x^2, y ≠ 0, x ≠ 0}
 , Simplify[expr ∈ Reals && expr < 0]]

(* False *)
```

But this breaks my ability to automate this computation.  How do I decide whether a rational expression is real and negative in a simpler way?

Comment: If x and y and expr are all real, doesn't this mean that (-1)^(1/3) is just -1?

Comment: `(-1)^(1/3) = 0.500 + 0.867 I `

Comment: (-1)^(1/3) = 0.500 + 0.867 I  or 0.500 + 0.867 I or -1. If you choose a complex root of -1, how can expr be real?

Comment: It can't.  And I want *Mathematica* to tell me that.  How do I do that in an automated way.  Please note that the example given is one of many in a long list (read the first sentence of my post.).

Comment: @bills - If you want `-1` then you would need to use [`CubeRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html) or [`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FullSimplify` (instead of `Simplify`) and you can remove most of the extra assumptions.

```
expr = ((-1)^(1/3)*(x^2 - y))/x^2;
Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}, 
     FullSimplify[expr \[Element] Reals && expr < 0]]

(* False *)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to test whether any expression is a negative real number for all (valid) real inputs. The OP's example should be `False` but it does not simplify to `False` with just `Simplify[]`.  With `FullSimplify[]`, the condition evaluates to `False` as desired.

Comment: The first part of your post answers my question and @MichaelE2 summarizes my request correctly.  I am editing your post to remove the unrelated and unneeded stuff near the end; please roll back if you wish.

Comment: You're right -- it's cleaner this way.